# C++ How to print this map std::map<int, pair<vector<pair<int, int>>, int>>

Tags: c++

I want to print pairs in map like:

```
std::map<int, pair<vector<pair<int, int>>, int>> Mymap;
```

**Example for data in this map:**

```
Mymap[0] = (0, ({ { 1, 3 }, { 1, 5 } }, 4))
Mymap[1] = (1, ({ { 2, 3 }, { 3, 7 }, { 1, 3 } }, 8))
```

I want to print pairs like:

```
{ 1, 3 }, { 1, 5 } 
{ 2, 3 }, { 3, 7 }, { 1, 3 }
```

Comment: Good for you!  Did you have a question?

Comment: Can you print the value from a map of ints -> ints? Or are you stuck on walking the map as well as pulling out the `first` part of a pair?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a blog post and not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a good first step is to actually write the example data such that it matches the type you've requested.

Perhaps something like:

```
Mymap[0] = {{{1, 3}, {1, 5}}, 4};
Mymap[1] = {{{2, 3}, {3, 7}, {1, 3}}, 8};
```

Then, we can pretty easily iterate over this...

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::pair<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>, int>> Mymap;

    Mymap[0] = {{{1, 3}, {1, 5}}, 4};
    Mymap[1] = {{{2, 3}, {3, 7}, {1, 3}}, 8};

    for (const auto & pair : Mymap) {
        for (const auto & pair : pair.second.first) {
            std::cout << "{" << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << "}, ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
{1, 3}, {1, 5}, 
{2, 3}, {3, 7}, {1, 3},
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any sense in your question, what exactly are you trying to do ?

Anyhow, this code should be able to do it:

```
    std::map<int, pair<vector<pair<int, int>>, int>> Mymap;
    Mymap[0] = {{{1, 3}, {1, 5}}, 4};
    Mymap[1] = {{{2, 3}, {3, 7}, {1, 3}}, 8};
    map<int, pair<vector<pair<int, int>>, int>>::iterator it;
    for (it=Mymap.begin(); it!=Mymap.end(); it++){
        pair<vector<pair<int, int>>, int> myPair=it->second;
        vector<pair<int, int>> myVec=myPair.first;
        for (int i=0; i<myVec.size(); i++){
            cout<< "{ " << myVec[i].first << ","<<myVec[i].second<< " }, ";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```